# Why does Installing Cocoapods gives File Permission Error

Tags: swift, ruby, terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods on my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) running a mac-os of Monterey version 12.6.1 using `$ sudo gem install cocoapods` on the terminal but it gives the following error.

```
apple@APPLEs-MBP ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0 directory.
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:712:in `verify_gem_home'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:902:in `pre_install_checks'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:302:in `install'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:104:in `install'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:194:in `block in install'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `install'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:210:in `install_gem'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:226:in `block in install_gems'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:219:in `install_gems'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:167:in `execute'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command.rb:323:in `invoke_with_build_args'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:185:in `process_args'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:149:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
apple@APPLEs-MBP ~ %
```

I am Using Xcode 14.1 (14b47b) and I also checked that the command line tools is also present and using a similar version. I have tried to install via Homebrew but when following the instruction at some point it ask me to install command line tools again. I still do this despite having the most recent version installed and after complete download it just do nothing. I have tried this process more than 10 times already.
When i use this code  `sudo gem update --system` it says latest version already installed. I have tried everything on stack-overflow it still will not work.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be trying to install into /Library since that is system wide and it is blocking you because that is the security policy. I would recommend rbenv or rvm (I prefer rbenv) and use those to have your development installs taking place in your folders like `~/Library/` .

Comment: Ah, I do not use CocaPods so I did not realize that while it is a gem, it is used for Xcode development. I would still try installing it in your `~/Library`.

Comment: @Beartech thanks for replying me, can you please point me to a solution?

Comment: have you tried the sudo-less install mentioned in the docs? https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

Comment: No, I will give that a try now

Comment: No, I will give that a try now

Comment: @Beartech I tried the sudo-less install and now i have a new error which says `WARNING:  You don't have /Users/apple/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/apple/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-try-1.2.0`

Comment: Did you do the `export...` commands as recommended? Can you do `which ruby` to see what that says? The error is telling you that you don't have `/Users/apple/.gem...` in your PATH. Do you understand what PATH does?

Comment: When I did which ruby , this is what it says `apple@APPLEs-MBP ~ % which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally resolved the error and I am posting the processes used incase someone faces the exact same issue.

1. Firstly I ran `% ruby -v` and `% which ruby` with terminal and took note of my ruby version and path (This was the default Mac ruby).
2. I downloaded Command line tools `version 14.1` from https://developer.apple.com This version was the same version as my xcode and it was already installed with xcode but I download and installed anyway.
3. After the successful installation of the Command line tool, I moved on to download Hombrew and after the install was successful, I then installed the cocoapods using `% brew install cocoapods` in terminal. At this point point cocoapods was installed but not properly working. as it was giving an error about 40 gems and some manifest not found.
4. This prompt me to install ruby with `% brew install ruby` and after taking some time it was installed successfully with some instructions on how to change the default ruby to the newly installed ruby. The instructions where to run the following code in terminal.
   `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc $ echo 'export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib"' >> ~/.zshrc $ echo 'export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby/include"' >> ~/.zshrc $ source ~/.zshrc`
5. After doing step 4, run `% ruby -v` and `% which ruby` and you will see that your ruby path and ruby version has been changed.
6. Lastly I then installed Cocoapods using this `% sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` and it was all installed successfuly.

Comment: This saved me days of debugging!! Thanks!

Comment: @Christophe glad my answer could be of help! you are welcome.